# ASP.net c# - Different modes for redirecting user Edit and Add New

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a form which brings back a listing of customers in the db.  There is also an Add Customer button to add a new customer and a hyperlink where the user could edit existing customers. When clicking the edit link I am able to bring back the correct data for that customer but if I make changes and click the "Update" button it doesn't edit the existing data. The other problem is that the "Update" button is also present when redirecting to add a new customer (the user enters the data for the new customer and clicks "Update").  Is it possible to refer to different code for different actions (Add New or Edit)/queries?  Here is what I have so far.  Thank you for any help.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="chpContent" runat="server">
<div>
    <h2>Customer Listing</h2>
    <br />
</div>
<p style="text-align:center">
    <asp:Button ID="btnCustomer" class="button" runat="server" Text="Add New Customer" onclick="btnCustomer_Click" />
</p>

<asp:ListView ID="lv" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="lv_SelectedIndexChanged">
<LayoutTemplate>
  <table width="110%" class="TableListing">
  <tbody>
    <thead>
    <th width="150">Customer Name</th>
      <th width="150">Email</th>
      <th width="150">City</th>
      <th width="40">State</th>
      <th width="110">Phone</th>
      <th width="80">Modify</th>
    </thead>
    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>  

    <asp:DataPager ID="ItemDataPager" runat="server" PageSize="20">
        <Fields>
            <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="5" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>

</LayoutTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
     <td><%# Eval ("LastName") %>, <%# Eval ("FirstName") %></td>
     <td><%# Eval ("Email") %></td>
     <td><%# Eval ("City") %></td>
     <td><%# Eval ("State") %></td>
     <td><%# Eval ("Phone") %></td>
     <td>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "CustomerEdit.aspx?ID=" + Eval("CustomerID") %>' Text="Edit" />
    </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Here is my CustomerEdit.aspx page:

```
public partial class CustomerEdit : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Master.HighlightNavItem("Customers");

        int CustomerID = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

        //Declare the connection object
        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection();
        Conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;

        //Connect to the db
        Conn.Open();

        //Define query
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer where CustomerID=@CustomerID";

        //Declare the Command
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Conn);

        //Add the parameters needed for the SQL query
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", CustomerID);

        //Declare the DataReader
        SqlDataReader dr = null;

        //Fill the DataReader
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //Get the data
        if (dr.Read() == false)
            {
                //No Records
                dr.Close();
                Conn.Close();
                return;
            }

    txtFirstName.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
    txtLastName.Text = dr["LastName"].ToString();
    txtEmail1.Text = dr["Email"].ToString();
    txtEmail2.Text = dr["Email"].ToString();
    txtPassword1.Text = dr["Password"].ToString();
    txtPassword2.Text = dr["Password"].ToString();
    txtAddress1.Text = dr["Address1"].ToString();
    txtAddress2.Text = dr["Address2"].ToString();
    txtCity.Text = dr["City"].ToString();
    txtState.Text = dr["State"].ToString();
    txtZip.Text = dr["Zip"].ToString();
    txtPhone.Text = dr["Phone"].ToString();
    txtFax.Text = dr["Fax"].ToString();


    dr.Close();
    Conn.Close();

    }


    protected void btnCancel_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Customers.aspx");
    }


    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int CustomerID = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

        //Declare the connection object
        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection();
        Conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;

        //Connect to the db
        Conn.Open();


        //Define query
        string sql = "UPDATE Customer SET Fax=@Fax Where CustomerID=@CustomerID";

        //Declare the Command
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Conn);

        //Add the parameters needed for the SQL query
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", txtAddress1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address2", txtAddress2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", txtState.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", txtZip.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fax", txtFax.Text);

        //Execute the query
        int NumRows = 0;
        NumRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Conn.Close();

        lblUpdate.Text = "Updated " + NumRows.ToString() + " record";

    }

}
```

}

And my Customers.aspx.cs page where the user is redirected.

```
    public partial class Customers : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
          this.Master.HighlightNavItem("Customers");


        //Declare the connection object
        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection();
        Conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;

        //Connect to the db
        Conn.Open();

        //Define query
        string sql = "SELECT CustomerID, LastName, FirstName, Email, Password, Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip, Phone, Fax FROM Customer";

        //Declare a SQL Adapter
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, Conn);

        //Declare a DataTable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        //Populate the DataTable
        da.Fill(dt);

        //Bind the Listview
        lv.DataSource = dt;
        lv.DataBind();

        dt.Dispose();
        da.Dispose();
        Conn.Close();

    }

            protected void btnCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
              Response.Redirect("CustomerEdit.aspx");                

          }

            protected void lv_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Response.Redirect("CustomerEdit.aspx");
            }

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Update is not working because you overwrite the data on PageLoad. Use the `IsPostBack` to avoid that as:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Master.HighlightNavItem("Customers");

    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        int CustomerID = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

        //Declare the connection object
        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection();
        Conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;

        //Connect to the db
        Conn.Open();

        //Define query
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer where CustomerID=@CustomerID";

        //Declare the Command
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Conn);

        //Add the parameters needed for the SQL query
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", CustomerID);

        //Declare the DataReader
        SqlDataReader dr = null;

        //Fill the DataReader
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //Get the data
        if (dr.Read() == false)
            {
                //No Records
                dr.Close();
                Conn.Close();
                return;
            }

        txtFirstName.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
        txtLastName.Text = dr["LastName"].ToString();
        txtEmail1.Text = dr["Email"].ToString();
        txtEmail2.Text = dr["Email"].ToString();
        txtPassword1.Text = dr["Password"].ToString();
        txtPassword2.Text = dr["Password"].ToString();
        txtAddress1.Text = dr["Address1"].ToString();
        txtAddress2.Text = dr["Address2"].ToString();
        txtCity.Text = dr["City"].ToString();
        txtState.Text = dr["State"].ToString();
        txtZip.Text = dr["Zip"].ToString();
        txtPhone.Text = dr["Phone"].ToString();
        txtFax.Text = dr["Fax"].ToString();


        dr.Close();
        Conn.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I did that but I receive an error "Must declare the scalar variable "@CustomerID" at the code under the btnUpdate at NumRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  I don't understand what this means.  Isn't CustomerID declared at    "int CustomerID = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

Comment: Because you aren't adding it as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you.  Now the other part of my question was regarding using the EditCustomer.aspx page for both adding a new customer and editing an existing customer.  In the btnUpdate event, how can I differentiate which query to use depending on whether it is a new customer or existing one?

Comment: @user1576304 Add a flag, or use a different button, think and design something.

Comment: Why not use two separate pages - addcustomer.aspx and editcustomer.aspx for example. That would make it more simple for the users and save you any hassle.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I need to use the CustomerEdit.aspx page for both editing and adding customers. There was mention of using a mode, I believe in the Customer.aspx page, but I'm not sure how to redirect based on that. For instance, CustomerEdit.aspx?Mode=N (for new) and CustomerEdit.aspx?Mode=E (for edit). I can't find out how to use modes, whether it is specified in the Customers.aspx page or the redirect. Has anyone had experience with using modes?

Comment: @user1576304 I first answer to the Update issue. Now the Mode=N, and Mode=E is a way to do that.

Comment: So could I have my hyperlink read like this:     <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "CustomerEdit.aspx?Mode=E&ID=" + Eval("CustomerID") %>' Text="Edit" /> and then use an if statement with request.querystring to say if "Mode" is "E" then use this sql query, else use this sql query? Does that sound like it would work?  I'm not able to test it at this moment, but will as soon as I can. Thanks.